# Query changing from Object db with java to Google app engine JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, subquery

I wrote a query for search which is working fine for object db but now I have changed the DB and using app engine datastore.Can anyone help in changing the query accordingly. the query is

```
SELECT u FROM User_personal u WHERE lower(CONCAT(u.fname,u.lname)) LIKE 
lower('SOME_NAME) ORDER BY LOCATE(CONCAT(u.fname,u.lname),lower('SOME_NAME')), 
LENGTH(CONCAT(u.fname,u.lname))
```

I want to use  Jpa queries on app engine not JDO

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if Google's "Datastore" supports many of those FUNCTIONs. But then you would have considered that when choosing the datastore no?

Comment: Is there a possibility of getting the same results using different way in datastore?I can remove the concatination and lower things as they can be done in another way

Comment: Why not consult Google's docs on what functions they support?

Comment: Like exists but only for prefix matching but i need to search a word complete name